# Can i search Any Profile using LinkedIn API or Just My First and Second Level Connections?

Tags: linkedin-api

I am using Linked IN JS Api. And Have written a very simple people search where i can search people based on their firstname and lastname. But Results are coming only from my first and second level connections. I have my friend who created a new profile and he was not able to search through the interface i have developed. Since he does not have any connections. I am not sharing code here because i first want to understand the possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using people-search with keywords instead of people with First name and last name?

Comment: Ya i also did keyword search. Like I searched for "Java". So some people are getting 10 results some are getting 4 results. Based on their connections.

Comment: OK. I think you should take a look at this . https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/accessing-out-network-profiles